# Uploading photo to website with cloudinary - need absolute path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am using rails 3 to upload photos to my server with cloudinary and carrierwave.

```
class NutsController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper
  include NutsHelper

  def index
    if current_user
      @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
      @nuts = Nut.all
    else
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end

  def new
    # current_user
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    if params[:file].present?
      @upload = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:file])
      @picture = @upload["secure_url"]
    end

    @nut = Nut.new(url: [@picture])
    if @nut.save
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

<------------------------------------------>

```
<%= cloudinary_js_config %>
<h1>Create a Nushell</h1>
<%= form_for :nut, url: nuts_path do |f| %>

  <%= cl_image_upload_tag(:image_id) %>

  <%= f.submit "Nut it Up!"%>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

---

My file is named Yellow_Happy.jpg. When I print out params[:file], it returns 'Yellow_Happy.jpg'. To upload to cloudinary I need the entire path my file, i.e. Users/apprentice/Desktop/Yellow_Happy.jpg. Does anyone know how to specify the entire path of my file?

Comment: how are you uploading your file? Can you post your form and carrierwave code?

Comment: @Mandeep
<%= cloudinary_js_config %>
<h1>Create a Nushell</h1>
<%= form_for :nut, url: nuts_path do |f| %>

  <%= cl_image_upload_tag(:image_id) %>

  <%= f.submit "Nut it Up!"%>
<% end %>

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your Uploader code you have specified `storage :file` *which basically tells carrierwave to upload image inside your app* and *store_dir function tells where to upload your image*. You can even check it inside `app/public/uploads`. For more details checkout [`carrierwave documentation`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

If you look at [**`cloudinary documentation`**](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave) you only need **include Cloudinary::CarrierWave** in your uploader(unless you are using thumbnails or other carrierwave features). Your uploader should be something like:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  #storage :file  #You don't need it

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```